# Show success message on success

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to grasp the method of presenting messages to the user after success or failure of for example a form. Say I've got a post function like the one below, where my aim was to present a partial view but apparently this didn't work the way I thought it would. Any pointers on how I can show the partial view after submitting the form successfully? When doing it like in the code below I of course get redirected to the partial views instead of just showing them on the current view which was what I want it to.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(bool succeeded)
    {
        if (succeeded)
        {
            ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Success!";
            return View("_SuccessMessage");
        }

        else
        {
            ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Error!";
            return View("_ErrorMessage");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay on the same view just return your current view and set some flag on your model or on the dynamic ViewBag that request is success or error. Than in your view you can include _ErrorMessage or _SuccessMessage based on that flag and if that flag is not set just don't reneder any of those partials.
    Also if you have to redirect to another view and show success/error there, you can use TempData collection.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured as well. It just seems so odd to pass around booleans...

Comment: You can pass around your partial view name and use it in RenderPartial method. So if there is no partial view name don't render anything otherwise just call RenderPartial(ViewBag.StatusMessageView).